# Casting shared_ptr in initializer list

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, c++17, shared-ptr

Is it possible to up-cast a shared pointer object reference in an initializer list?

I have two class hierarchies with matching derived classes.  Let's say I have a `Base` class which is derived to a `Foo` and a `Bar` class.  Then I have a separate hierarchy with a `ProxyBase` class and then (to match the other hierarchy) there's `FooProxy` and `BarProxy`.

The `ProxyBase` class stores a `shared_ptr<Base>`.  When a `ProxyFoo` is created it requires a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>&`, when a `ProxyBar` is created it requires a `std::shared_ptr<Bar>&`.

There are two ways I can make this work:

- Don't use references to the `std::shared_ptr<*>` objects.
- Use `std::shared_ptr<Base>& obj` as input to the `ProxyFoo` and `ProxyBar` constructors.  This requires a down-cast (which I want to avoid) in the constructor (since I want the `Foo` and `Bar` specific properties), plus that it makes the contract/API more allowing than it should be.

But I'm wondering if this can be done with references.

I *think* I know what the problem is:  When I remove the references it works, and I think that's because "casting" a `shared_ptr<X>` is technically not allowed; it can only be "casted" by creating a new `shared_ptr` object of a derived/base type.  When using references one tries to actually cast one `shared_ptr` object to another which isn't allowed.  Is this correct?

Originally I thought this was one of those cases where `std::static_pointer_cast` would help, but if my hypothesis is correct then that won't help either.

Self-contained example:

```
#include <memory>

class Base { };

class Foo : public Base
{
private:
  int val_;

public:
  Foo(int val) : val_(val) { }
};

class ProxyBase
{
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<Base> obj_;

  ProxyBase(std::shared_ptr<Base>& obj) : obj_(obj) { }
};

class FooProxy : public ProxyBase
{
public:
  FooProxy(std::shared_ptr<Foo>& fobj) : ProxyBase(fobj) { }
};

int main()
{
  auto f = std::make_shared<Foo>(42);
  auto fp = std::make_shared<FooProxy>(f);
}
```

So my question boils down to:  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in the (currently non-functional) code above without removing the references and yet keep the `Foo` and `Bar` specific constructors to `FooProxy` and `BarProxy`?

Comment: Why do you have (non const) reference?

Comment: @Jarod42 Because of pure ignorance.  :)  I had imagined that a const would have made the shared_ptr objects completely immutable (i.e. not clone:able (to use Rust speak)), but Barry's answer makes it clear that I have severe knowledge gaps wrt const and shared_ptr.

Comment: Smart ptr semantics follow ptr semantics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `shared_ptr<Derived>` can be *converted* to a `shared_ptr<Base>`, but it *is not* a `shared_ptr<Base>`.

In other words, this compiles:

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> pd;
std::shared_ptr<Base> pb = pd;
```

But this does not:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base>& pb = pd;
```

But this does, because const references can bind to temporaries and this will implicitly perform a conversion:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> const& pb = pd;
```

The problem is that you're taking non-const lvalue references in your constructors. You should either take const lvalue references or just take them by value.

Comment: Most certainly it should be by-value and then moveing.